# Running Visual Studio as Admin breaks scripting hotkey in Firefox (just curious about why)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, autoit

I created a very simple [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/) script that simulates the keys for my login on a website I'm working on. All the script does is send "testUser{Tab}testPassword{enter}", where tab and enter are related keys, this happens when I press the ` key.

When I run Visual Studio with admin privileges this hotkey no longer works and I always just get the ` instead of my login (if you can't replicate try restarting your browser). Does anyone know why?

Edit: Here's my autoit script:

```
HotKeySet('`', '_SendLogin')

While 1
    Sleep(200)
WEnd

Func _SendLogin()
    Send('Jimmy{TAB}password{ENTER}')
EndFunc
```

Comment: Can you post the code you used, excluding username & password, to the question (this will give us a better understanding of how you are trying to do this)?

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove Just did.

Comment: I'm thinking this has something to do with Visual Studio's default keyboard shortcuts, but I would think that only would work if Visual Studio was the active window.

Comment: Try adjusting the `sleep()` command to wait longer than 200 milliseconds, something like 5000 millisecond (5 seconds). Then, give it another try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A process that runs without UAC elevation cannot poke anything into an elevated process.  Called UIPI ([User Interface Privilege Isolation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vishalsi/archive/2006/11/30/what-is-user-interface-privilege-isolation-uipi-on-vista.aspx)), the lesser known aspect of UAC.  It prevents an unelevated app from hijacking an elevated one to work around a UAC restriction.  With, for example, keystroke injection.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like VB resets the state of the hotkeys.

Maybe try adding **#RequireAdmin** to the top of your script.

Here is another workaround:

```
While 1
    HotKeySet('`', '_SendLogin')
    Sleep(1000)
WEnd

Func _SendLogin()
    Send('Jimmy{TAB}password{ENTER}')
EndFunc
```

Comment: #RequireAdmin allowed my script to work. I selected the other answer because I felt it explained why better.